# htaccess setting environment variable

Tags: .htaccess, environment-variables

I'm trying to get following code to work, but it seems like the environment variable `SETEXPIRE` is never set. If I remove the `IfDefine SETEXPIRE` part it works, but I need that part.

```bash
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews

# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)_=(.*)
RewriteRule .* - [E=SETEXPIRE:yes]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^html/(.*?)$ index.php?url=$1&%{QUERY_STRING} [L,NC]

<IfDefine SETEXPIRE>
    <filesMatch "(?!\.(png|jpe?g|css|js|gif))$">
        <IfModule mod_expires.c>
            ExpiresActive On
            ExpiresDefault "access plus 3 months"

            <IfModule mod_headers.c>
                Header set Cache-Control "max-age=2592000, public, no-transform"
                Header set pragma ""
            </IfModule>
        </IfModule>
    </filesMatch>
</IfDefine>
```

Any help would be appreciated.

what im trying to do is to set expire header if the file extension requested is one of png|jpe?g|css|js|gif and key _ is set in the query string

Comment: I don't think `IfDefine` checks environment variables. It checks command line switch definitions. So it would work, for example, if your server was started with the `-D SETEXPIRE` switch (just using that as an example to explain how I understand it to work).

Comment: Hi Mike ... thnx for the quick answer ... do you have any idea of how i get the code to work?

Comment: Well I'm not *exactly* sure of what you are trying to do here, to be honest. Please could you explain?

Comment: see edited text in question :-)

Comment: Right, I thought as much. Might be worth looking at [this](/questions/8806183/how-to-set-the-x-robots-tag-http-header-via-htaccess-file-based-on-url-query-st) to start.

Comment: thnx Mike .... figured out the solution from the link :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thnx to mike i found a solution:

```
 Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
 # Turn mod_rewrite on
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteBase /

 RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)_=(.*)
 RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !(^|&)_=0(&|$)
 RewriteRule .* - [E=SETEXPIRE:yes]

 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteRule ^html/(.*?)$ index.php?url=$1&%{QUERY_STRING} [L,NC]

 <filesMatch "(?!\.(png|jpe?g|css|js|gif))$">
       Header set Cache-Control "max-age=2592000, public, no-transform" env=SETEXPIRE
       Header set pragma "" env=SETEXPIRE
  </filesMatch>
```

cheers
c_bb